# Cloudera Oozie Cannot submit workflow

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, hue

I am using the free version of CDH, I am trying to schedule a sqoop job using oozie.. however, after I created a workflow node, I am trying to submit that job to just test it. Then I planned to use coordinator to schedule it if it succeeded. However, it failed and here is how the log looks like:

What I have tried:

I tested the sqoop command from command line as root, and it worked, I thought it might be permission issues, and then I change the ownership of the target directory to be `hue:hive`, however it still failed due to the same reason.

Can anyone help me what is going on here:

```
    2014-12-24 10:46:22,286 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] Start action [0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
    2014-12-24 10:46:22,286 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action status=DONE
    2014-12-24 10:46:22,286 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@:start:] [***0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@:start:***]Action updated in DB!
    2014-12-24 10:46:23,228 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line] Start action [0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
    2014-12-24 10:46:23,750 INFO org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopActionExecutor: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line] checking action, hadoop job ID [job_1416871205984_5182] status [RUNNING]
    2014-12-24 10:46:23,752 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line] [***0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line***]Action status=RUNNING
    2014-12-24 10:46:23,752 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line] [***0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line***]Action updated in DB!
    2014-12-24 10:46:43,233 INFO org.apache.oozie.servlet.CallbackServlet: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line] callback for action [0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line]
    2014-12-24 10:46:43,730 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionEndXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@butters_node_order_line] ERROR is considered as FAILED for SLA
    2014-12-24 10:46:44,344 INFO org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@kill] Start action [0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@kill] with user-retry state : userRetryCount [0], userRetryMax [0], userRetryInterval [10]
    2014-12-24 10:46:44,344 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@kill] [***0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@kill***]Action status=DONE
    2014-12-24 10:46:44,344 WARN org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand: SERVER[701.datafireball.com] USER[hue] GROUP[-] TOKEN[] APP[butters_order_line] JOB[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W] ACTION[0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@kill] [***0000445-141124182113147-oozie-oozi-W@kill***]Action updated in DB!
```

Comment: Could you click on the Log icon on the Sqoop action in the workflow dashboard, it should show more logs about the problem?

Comment: Also, please provide the command used in the Sqoop action.